# Why can't I build in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i run the build in flutter, it will not proceed at this stage, below is the status of flutter doctor.
I don't know which part is wrong.

I get the following error, the installed package doesn't seem to match the version of flutter, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
 Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for arm64 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Note: /Users/madol.eeee/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geocoding/GeocodingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/Users/madol.eeee/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-2.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
/Users/madol.eeee/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-2.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
      position.put("is_mocked", location.isMock());
                                        ^
  symbol:   method isMock()
  location: variable location of type Location

2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-arm, locale ko-KR)
• Flutter version 2.5.2 at /Users/madol.eeee/Downloads/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 3595343e20 (7 days ago), 2021-09-30 12:58:18 -0700
• Engine revision 6ac856380f
• Dart version 2.14.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/madol.eeee/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: /Users/madol.eeee/Downloads/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 13.0, Build version 13A233
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at /Users/madol.eeee/Downloads/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
• VS Code at /Users/madol.eeee/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.27.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• sdk gphone arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
• Chrome (web)              • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 94.0.4606.71
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Android Studio--> Tools --> AVD Manager

`wipedata` of simulator

again `run`

Comment: I have corrected the question, please check it again, thank you.

Comment: Open LastKnownLocationUsingLocationServicesTask file, delete the import statement which is causing this error, again import it using option + enter, I have seen this issue while using geolocator.

Similarly, open LocationUpdatesUsingLocationServicesTask file and delete import (with errors) and reimport it.